# Duda aplicaciones desarrollada hace años

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, javazoom

Muy buenas,

vereis hace 5 años desarrolle una aplicación web con frontend y backend con la capa logica en Java. Y he decidido volver a utilizar esa aplicacion con fines comerciales. Pero me encuentro que no me funciona bien cuando en su dia iba todo perfectamente. Lo primero que he hecho ha sido desplegarla en tomcat como cuando funcionaba en su dia, pero he notado que las consultas o inserciones a la base de datos no las llegaba a hacer. Entonces he decidido desplegarla en netbeans a ver que le estaba ocurriendo, y mi sorpresa es que da varios errores. Creo que estan relacionados con las librerias. No se si es que estarán obsoletas, pero adjunto una foto con las librerias que muestra o bien que no se han encontrado dichas librerias o bien un error de broken references. Ya he realizado un clean and build pero siguen los mismos errores.
Agradeceria todas las soluciones posibles, y de agradecer tambien el porque puede ser que si la aplicacion iba todo perfectamente en su dia, ahora dé tantos problemas ya sea en tomcat directamente desplegado o en un IDE.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

**El problema es que no existen las bibliotecas definidas en el proyecto, estas se deberían encontrar en el directorio `/libs`, seguramente no las tienes.**

Lo que debes realizar, es crear (si es que no existe) el directorio `/libs` en la raíz de tu proyecto, buscar y descargar las bibliotecas, por ejemplo puedes descargar desde aquí:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsfileupload13jar.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio24jar.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcosjar.htm
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11

y usar la opción `Add JAR/Folder`, para agregarlas desde ahí a tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado, he creado una carpeta en el nivel donde estan las otras carpetas como /dist, /build /src. He añadido esa carpeta /libreria mediante add JAR/Folder, importa la carpeta con los .jar. Pero no enlaza bien con los servlets. Pero si importo los .jar directamente todos sin importar la carpeta, si que enlaza bien y desaparecen los errores. Lo puedo dejar asi, o en el futuro si vuelvo a instalar el programa en otro equipo diferente me dará problemas?. Gracias de nuevo.